# Knex why is GROUP_CONCAT repeating the column name rather than the column value? (MySQL 5.7)

Tags: javascript, mysql, knex.js

I'm writing a migration file in knex to add a view to our MySQL 5.7 database.

This migration creates a view for a query that uses `GROUP_CONCAT`.

I'm using the following code to create this view. It's very close to working, but the GROUP_CONCAT is concatting the value "pf.family" repeatedly rather than the actual column value for pf.family.

```
/**
 * @param { import("knex").Knex } knex
 * @returns { Promise<void> }
 */
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.createViewOrReplace(
    "product_families_view",
    function (view) {
      view.columns(["product_id", "part_number", "families"]);
      view.as(
        knex("product_families AS pf")
          .select([
            "pfp.product_id",
            "pfp.part_number",
            knex.raw("GROUP_CONCAT(? ORDER BY ? SEPARATOR ?) as ?", [
              "pf.family",
              "pf.family",
              " ",
              "families",
            ]),
          ])
          .innerJoin(
            "product_families_products AS pfp",
            "pfp.family_id",
            "pf.id"
          )
          .groupBy("pfp.product_id")
      );
    }
  );
};
```

This results in the following view:

[image: Result set for view]

I'm unsure why "pf.family" is repeated rather than the actual pf.family column values I'm trying to concat.

Comment: That's what `knex.raw()` is supposed to do. If you want the parameters to be interpreted as part of the query context (i.e., as column references), then you don't want to use `.raw()`.

Comment: @Pointy perhaps you mean when you're using bindings? That does seem right, when I change the raw query to the following 

```
 knex.raw(
              "GROUP_CONCAT(pf.family ORDER BY pf.family SEPARATOR ' ') as families"
            )
```

it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Whoops. Looks like using bindings causes the issue.

```
/**
 * @param { import("knex").Knex } knex
 * @returns { Promise<void> }
 */
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.createViewOrReplace(
    "product_families_view",
    function (view) {
      view.columns(["product_id", "part_number", "families"]);
      view.as(
        knex("product_families AS pf")
          .select([
            "pfp.product_id",
            "pfp.part_number",
            knex.raw(
              "GROUP_CONCAT(pf.family ORDER BY pf.family SEPARATOR ' ') as families"
            ),
          ])
          .innerJoin(
            "product_families_products AS pfp",
            "pfp.family_id",
            "pf.id"
          )
          .groupBy("pfp.product_id")
      );
    }
  );
};
```

This resolved the problem

Comment: Yea, I think that's what I meant :) I've got only a tiny amount of knex experience.